# Laravel check box validation - user must select at least one check box

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-validation

I have checked out several post with similar question ( [for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38614494/force-user-to-pick-at-least-one-checkbox-laravel) ) But did not quite found the answer I am looking for.

I am working on a Laravel multi-step form. and in one of the step the code for the form is like following

```
<form action= {{ route('complaints.post.step.two') }} method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    @foreach ($rules as $rule)
    <div class="cell">
        <input type="checkbox"  name="{{ $rule->id }}" >
        <label> {{ $rule->rule }} </label>
    </div>
    @endforeach

    <div class="cell">
            <input type="submit" name="save" value="Next">
    </div>
</form>
```

Check-boxes in this form are dynamically generated from database query. user can select as many check box they want but must select at least one.

How to achieve that with laravel validate method.

I have tried the following code in my controller. But it keeps showing the error message if user selects only one or few check box. For some reason the message is shown even with all the check boxes are checked

```
    $rules = [
        'rule' => 'required' 
    ];
    $customMessages = [
        'required' => 'You have to select a  rule'
    ];
    
    $validatedData = $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);
```

please Note - The number of check box items are not fixed . It depends on the data selected on previous steps.

Comment: `name='{{ $rule->id }}'` doesn't look correct; that would be `name="1"` (for example). You'd want something like `name="rules[]" value="{{ $rule->id }}"`, then you'd validate the Array of `rules`, like `['rules' => 'array|required|min:1']`. See the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#validating-arrays

Comment: @TimLewis - thank you. it worked in the way you suggested.